# Why aren't i able to append the values in my dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
keys = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]
squares_dict = {key: None for key in keys}

def box_number(my_dict,xmax,ymax,xmin,ymin,key):
    ra = Rectangle(float(xmax),
                   float(ymax),
                   float(xmin),
                   float(ymin))
    # print(area(ra, Rectangle(float(my_dict[key][2][0]),float(my_dict[key][3][0]),0,0)))
    if area(ra, Rectangle(float(my_dict[key][2][0]),float(my_dict[key][3][0]),0,0)) == area(ra,ra):

        squares_dict[1].append(key,xmax,ymax,xmin,ymin)//This line
```

The issue i'm having is related to the last line of the code shared, the error i'm getting is `squares_dict[1].append(key,xmax,ymax,xmin,ymin)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: you created your dict with `None` as values what did you expect? `squares_dict = {key: list() for key in keys}` is better

Comment: After i've done that i got this error `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (5 given)` how can i make it append a list of 5 items.

Comment: and kindly add the change in answers so i can accept it.

Comment: If what you want to append is a list of 5 elements instead the elements themselves just use `squares_dict[1].append([key,xmax,ymax,xmin,ymin])`... you can replace the `[]` with `()` (list vs. tuple. Both will be accepted by `append`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all your values are `None` in your dict. You could create empty lists as values.

```
squares_dict = {key: [] for key in keys}
```

or even better maybe, get rid of the creation and use `defaultdict`

```
import collections
squares_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

so first time, if key isn't in the dict, the `defaultdict` creates a new, empty list.

And after that, you have to append a `tuple`, not several values (`append` only accepts one argument):

```
squares_dict[1].append((key,xmax,ymax,xmin,ymin))
```

Answer (score 0):

`squares_dict = {key: None for key in keys}` means `squares_dict` holds keys and the value of each key is `None`, which in turns means `squares_dict[1]` is None and `NoneType` has no append attribute

Comment: KIndly check my comment on the question for the error i got after adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change None to a proper value.
For example instead of  None try a variable thats defined or a string/integer